# How to find the cutoff frequency using Simulink (from the scope)?

Tags: oscilloscope, low-pass, simulink, cutoff-frequency

[image: RC Circuit]

[image: Scope Result]

- R=1000 ohm
- C=0.1uF

I need to find the cutoff frequency from the scope and to show it matches the theory \$f= \frac{1}{2pi*RC}\$

In this case it's 1591Hz.

How do I measure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onother way you can achieve that in the time domain, is through the following:

1. Apply a low frequency pure sinusoidal at the input
2. Measure the RMS at the capacitor
3. Sweep the input frequency
4. Measure the RMS again at the capacitor
5. Repeat Steps 3 to 4 until the ratio \$\dfrac{V_{OUT, RMS}}{V_{in, RMS}}\approx 0.707\$, which is one of the definitions of the \$3_{dB}\$ corner frequency

Here is a simulation which emulates this measurement:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Measure the time constant, \$\tau\$, of one of the exponentials (63% response time), and the cut-off frequency is the inverse of this, in rad/sec.

The scope's time and vertical scales need minor gridlines, but it looks like \$\tau\approx 10^{-4} \: sec; \:\therefore \omega_c\approx\large \frac{1}{10^{-4}}\small=10^4 rad/sec; \: f_c =1591 Hz\$

Comment: YES WORK FINE! THANKS!